# Convert Month_Dt In sas

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have a sample data in this format as char.

```
Month
2008-09 
2007-10 
2008-09
```

How to get the above as date '01sep2008' (SAS DESIGN STUDIO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  Dirk has a good method concatenating a day onto the string and using the `INPUT()` function.

You could also use the `yymmn6.` informat with the `INPUT()`.  That requires you to strip the '-' from the string.

```
data test;
x = '2008-05';
format y date9.;
y = input(compress(x,"-"),yymmn6.);
put y;
run;
```

You could use the `MDY()` to specify the Month, Day and Year.  Here you use the `SCAN()` function to pick out the month and year from the string using '-' as a delimiter.

```
data test;
x = '2008-05';
format y date9.;
y = mdy(scan(x,2,'-'),1,scan(x,1,'-'));
put y;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is Working fine.  +Why we have used Put y at the end. Is it required?

Answer (score 1):

## Use an input function

An input function is a function that interpretes a **character variable** using an informat. _(This is not exactly the same as an input statement, which interpretes text in an `infile` according to an informat.)

There might be an informat that imidiately interpretes strings like `2008-09` correctly, but I don't know one, so I just add a `_01` to it and apply the informat `yymmdd10.`

## Example

Depending on your situation (the data is inform a file or a dataset / you prefer data steps or sql / ...) the full solution would look like this:

```
data Before;
    input the_date $7.;
    datalines;
2008-09 
2007-10 
2008-09
;
data After;
    set Before (rename=(the_date=old_date));
    format the_date date9.;
    the_date = input(old_date||'-01', yymmdd10.);
    * while testing the code, uncomment the following line :
    drop old_date;

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: INFORMATs  and FORMATs are similar but distinct things in SAS. The INPUT() function and the INPUT statement use informats, not formats.